# Styling radio buttons on ActionBarCompat dropdown menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am working on an app that uses a theme that extends `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

On one of my activities, there is an Action Bar icon that shows three options with radiobuttons (here's an extract from the menu XML file):

```
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter_white"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""
    preparatest:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_filter_all"                    
                android:title="@string/history_list_filter_all"
                android:checked="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_filter_pending"
                android:title="@string/history_list_filter_pending"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_filter_finished"
                android:title="@string/history_list_filter_finished"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

I want to give these radiobuttons a custom style, but I don't know where to do it. On my styles.xml file I have defined the custom style as

```
<style name="RadioButtonPTGreenTheme" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/ptgreentheme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

and tried using all these four options, but to no avail:

`<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonPTGreenTheme</item>`

`<item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@style/RadioButtonPTGreenTheme</item>`

`<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@drawable/ptgreentheme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>`

`<item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/ptgreentheme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>`

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [blog post](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/the-unknown-style-actionbarwidgettheme.html) for a way to do it.

Long story short, `android:actionBarWidgetTheme` is used to style elements that depend on the Action Bar, so the `android:radioButtonStyle` should be put inside a style for actionBarWidgetTheme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionBarWidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarWidgetTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/MyRadioButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dan, that worked! :) Do you mind if I edit your post to add the actual code example from the blog post?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you'd probably want that the parent of the style you use for the radioButtonStyle is "Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton", and there you can change "android:button" and "android:background".