# Radio Button style in Menu with Toolbar not working

Tags: android, styles, menuitem

I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985442/styling-radio-buttons-on-actionbarcompat-dropdown-menu) for applying style on radio button in Toolbar menuitem but it is not working for me. I want to apply check mark style for radio button in MenuItem so please help me with proper guidance.

**Style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activity_bg</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionBarWidgetTheme</item>
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionBarWidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarWidgetTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!--<item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/radiobutton_selector_checkmark</item>-->
        <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/Widget.RadioButton.CheckMark</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.RadioButton.CheckMark" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/radiobutton_selector</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/radiobutton_selector</item>
</style>
```

And here is output

[image]

**Menu.xml**

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_filter"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter_white_24dp"
android:orderInCategory="2"
android:title="@string/action_filter"
app:showAsAction="always">

<menu>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/filter_favorite"
            android:title="Favorites"
            android:checked="true"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/filter_myProject"
            android:title="My Projects"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/filter_completed"
            android:title="Completed"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/filter_all"
            android:title="All Projects"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. please help me...

Comment: any luck???????

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but if anyone is looking for an answer, here is a link on how to do it (the details are at the end) : https://www.zoftino.com/android-ui-control-radiobutton

You have to use `selector` :

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

and where `drawable/radio_checked` and `drawable/radio_unchecked` are your fake checkbox.